# osTicket, auto assignation by account

Tags: automation, custom-lists, osticket

I am evaluating osTicket for a company who repair printers.

When company's customers need support, they have to log in osTicket to open a issue.

First, they have to be able to select one device id (or serial number) of their broken printer. For this, I will need to populate the relation **id_device-account** in somewhere. Then they will select the kind of issue and will apport other datas.

After the issue was saved, the system have to assig that ticket to a technician (for this I will need to populate a second list with the relation between **staff-memebers and accounts**).

**Where can I define these lists with relations** (device-account and staff-member-account) **and how can I performed these automations?**

Thanks in advance and regards,
Gonzalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gonzalo, Following the answer from @Joshua Walcher all you need to do is add your form under the *Ticket Details* under Manage > Forms > Ticket Details. Once there just create your custom entry and define it as you need, you can even choose the order in which it's displayed on the Client Page and assign variables to that field. Once there it should appear in all of the tickets they create. I use this for information we need to pull and made it mandatory, If you need to assign based on value just use the Tickets Filter as previously mentioned by @Joshua. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is built into osTicket. Or at least it is for the latest version.

You will need to set up a custom form: Admin -> Manage -> Forms and then add your printer values into the main support form.

Then you need to go to Manage -> Ticket Filter. In there, you can assign filters  based on the custom form's field for each printer type (or multiple printer types if you want) and have them sent to specific agents or to agent teams or departments under the action tab.

Comment: @Josua Walcher thank for your help. I will try that you said. It would be fantastic if it was possible to use my custom form like company's ticket form. Is it possible?

Comment: That's how I'm using it on another project - the custom form integrates with the default form, @Gonzalo, and then the tickets get shipped off to the various support staff based on the options chosen by the end user. It should work well for your use case.

Comment: Thankyou again @Josua-walcher. I tried that you said but I found only one way to include my custom form... I have to include it in a help topic (I don't want to  do that). What I doing wrong? Regards.